# erlang: How to get an element form a list by its positional index?

Tags: python, erlang

In python if I want to retrieve the second element of a list, I can do it like this:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3]
>>> A[1]
2
```

What is the equivalent of it in erlang?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can use the `nth` method in the `lists` module.

```
1> A = [1, 2, 3].
[1,2,3]
2> lists:nth(2, A).
2
```

**Note**: The index is not zero based.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Why is it complicated? Erlang is a functional programming language. Like nearly all list operations, this one is managed with a simple function call. I actually can't imagine a design that would be more simple within the context of Erlang.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij I'm so confused. A function call is bloated? What language are you comparing this to that provides a simpler API for accessing an element of a Linked List by index?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij For example, on your profile you say you're in love with Flutter. What part of Dart's [interface for LinkedLists](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html) is less complicated in your mind?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij
Hmm. Are you sure you know the difference between a LinkedList (called `LinkedList` in Dart) and a Array (called `List` in Dart)? Because `object[index]` is NOT how you access a LinkedList by index in Dart.
On the contrary, in Dart, _just like Erlang_, you access an element with—wait for it—a simple _function call_: `myLinkedList.elementAt(index)`.
Even non-FP languages support basic function calls. Which is all this is, a basic function call.
By the way, Dart has first-class functions and supports many FP constructs. It's actually more like Erlang than you think.

Comment: @AustinYork Yeah I'm sorry. I don't know anything. Enjoy life.

Comment: Oh and I know what a linkedlist is. Also I'm saying lists.getindex(index, list) looks bad. And I never said I was accessing a linkedlist by index. You brought in linkedlist in middle of a discussion about lists for no reason. Also I deleted all my comments to make you feel accomplished. Enjoy.